# How can I check if two codes written in C in two different styles are equivalent?

Tags: c

How can I check if two codes written in C in two different styles are equivalent?

**Style 1:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define K1 42
#define K2 1200

int i1, i2, i3 = -10;
unsigned u1, u2 = 1230, u3 = K1, u4;

int main( void ) {
    
    scanf( "%d", &i2 );
    scanf( "%u", &u1 );
    for ( i1 = i2 - 1; i2 < i3-i1 || u2 >= u1; u2 = u3, u3 = u3 % ++u4 ) {
        i2 = i2 / 2 + i3++;
        scanf( "%u", &u4 );
        do {
            i3 -= K2;
            u4 = ( u4 << 2 ) & ~ 0x04;
            i1 = i3 / i2;
        } while ( u4 < K1 && i1 + 23 >= i2 + 4 );
        u3 = --u1 + ( u4 -= 2);
    }
    u1 = ( u4 - u2 ) * 5 + ( u2 + u3 ) / 6 - u1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Style 2:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define K1 42
#define K2 1200

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
int i3 = -10;
int t;
unsigned u1 = 0;
unsigned u2 = 1230;
unsigned u3 = K1;
unsigned u4 = 0 ;

int main(){

    scanf( "%d", &i2 );
    scanf( "%d", &u1 );
    i1 = i2 - 1;
    t = i3 - i1;
    
for_beg:
    if ( i2 < t ) goto for_tt;
    if ( u2 >= u1 ) goto for_tt;
    goto for_ff;

for_tt:
    i2 = i2 / 2;
    i2 += i3;
    i3 += 1;
    scanf( "%u", &u4 );
    
do_begin:
    i3 -= K2;
    u4 = u4 << 2;
    u4 = ~ 0x04;
    i1 = i3 / i2;
    
while_beg:
    if ( u4 >= K1 ) goto while_ff;
    t = i1 + 23;
    int t2 = i2 + 4;
    if ( t < t2 ) goto while_ff;
    goto do_begin;
    
while_ff:
    u1 -= 1;
    u4 -= 2;
    u3 = u1 + u4;

for_end:
    u4 += 1;
    u3 %= u4;
    goto for_beg;
    
for_ff:
    t = u4 - u2;
    t2 = u2 + u3;
    t *= 5;
    t2 /= 6;
    t += t2;
    t -= u1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

More than to verify code line by line, I should use a debug tool?
Thank you!

I tried execute codes with printing the `u1` variable but the code still going in loop

Comment: In your question, you wrote: `"I tried execute codes with printing u1 variable's but the code still going in loop"` -- If you suspect that the code is getting stuck in an infinite loop, then you can run your code line by line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to see what is going on. Also, if you want to print the values of variables when you are inside an infinite loop, I recommend that you call `fflush(stdout);` after printing these values, otherwise they may never get printed, if the stream is never flushed.

Comment: In order to test whether both programs are equivalent, you can test both programs with the same input and then compare the results. You may want to use multiple variations of the input, so that the tests are more extensive.

Comment: Using `goto` is considered bad practice (because it may make understanding the logic of a program difficult) and should not be used.

Comment: code 2 was written by an assembler programmer :) Both do not check if the input data and if scanf did not fail

Answer (score 1):

You can check by *reading the codes*, which are not equivalent.

The first code has

```
u4 = ( u4 << 2 ) & ~ 0x04;
```

and the second code has

```
u4 = u4 << 2;
u4 = ~ 0x04;
```

overwriting `u4`.

OT: don't write code like that: C largely frees us from having to use labels and assembler style coding.

Comment: I saw those 2 lines and I surely read `u4 &= ~ 0x04;` another amazing example of *what you see is not what is written* :)

Answer (score 0):

It is non trivial to prove these 2 codes are equivalent and I am not aware of any tools that can achieve this in the general case.

The second instance seems to be a broken down version with labels and gotos along with common expression factorisation.

Showing a single counter example is a way to prove that the codes are not equivalent, but finding a counterexample may not be easy and downright impossible if the codes are indeed equivalent.

A way to prove equivalence would be to rewrite the code incrementally into equivalent constructions that can be proven. If one can reach the second instance, then the codes can be considered equivalent.  The problem is it is not so easy even for simple cases to prove exact equivalence for all corner cases.

In the question codes, there is a problem with variables used for temporary subexpressions: a global variable `t` is used to store the value of the expression `i3 - i1` used in the outer `for` loop test, and the same `t` variable is used in the inner loop for another calculation... the second iteration of the outer loop uses the current value of `t` in `if ( i2 < t ) goto for_tt;` which seems incorrect.  Note that `i3` is modified in the loop body, so `t = i3 - i1;` should be recomputed for every iteration anyway.

I am willing to bet one dollar that the codes are not equivalent...

Answer (score -1):

> How can i check if two codes wrote in C in two different styles are equivalent?

In *general* this question is equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and is un-answerable.

You can try to generate a set of random inputs and verify that both programs produce the same result. If they do for (say) 10,000 inputs, they are *probably* equivalent.

Comment: *they are probably equivalent*: are you serious?